# How can I run node v10.x on Azure Functions on a Linux host?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I've been working on a small function to automate my certificate renewal in Azure Functions.

The function works in my local emulator (in vscode), running under node v10.15.3.

However, when running it online, an exeption is generated on the syntax of an async iterator when the file containing it is included

```
Stack: /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/acme-dns-01-cloudflare/index.js:125
                for await(const zone of consumePages(pagination =>
```

It's my understanding that this syntax has been adopted in node versions 10.x. I therefore added the console output line: `console.log(process.versions);` and get the response that the function is running node version 8.16.1. I therefore checked the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION application setting, and confirmed it is set to 10.14.1. I have also checked it with another recommended setting of ~10 and got the same result.

Unfortunately the documentation is difficult to search for such a specific issue, but I have not yet come across anything that states that Linux functions are limited to node v8.x

As extra information, the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME is set to "node", and the runtime version is 2.0.12733.0 (~2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time of writing, this issue on github highlights the problem https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4948. Different node versions are simply not available on Linux consumption plans regardless of the setting in WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION.

Hopefully their new arrangements will be in place soon for anyone else who has this issue.

For now you can switch to a windows consumption plan, or potentially switch to a service plan (I haven't checked this, as it sort of defeats the point of functions)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [issue1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3406) and [issue2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4639), looks like `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` won't work for linux function, have to set the `LinuxFxVersion` property to select the node version.

Follow is my flow to change it.

1.Go to your Function App in the portal and open the [Resource Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENaqF.png). You will find `LinuxFxVersion` is `node:2.0-node8-appservice`.

[image]

2.Select the web under config node, then choose the Edit button. Find the `linuxFxVersion` and change the value to `NODE|10.14`, after this click the PUT button to update the setting. Then restart your Function, check the node version you will find it's 10.14.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the change in this value does not stick, the PUT operation succeeds, but does not alter the value. In addition, my existing value is blank, not the value you suggested. I am deploying this app from a zip file by url, using the functions extension in vscode if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Jamesmp, did you use the consumption plan.

Comment: For now the consumption plan linux doesn't support to upgrade the version you have to wait the Azure to upgrade it, if you want to use it you could choose to use the windows os.

Comment: I did, ok, thanks for your help. It's a shame that the documentation isn't better for this. I ended up switching to a windows host.

Comment: @Jamesmp, got a response from PG, for now it doesn't support Node 8 for Linux Consumption, and they are working on onboarding Node 10. So they will upgrade Node 10 version later.